# Tail vs sleep to wait on process

Tags: bash, process, sleep, pid, tail

Currently I do:

```
while [ -d "/proc/$PID"  ]; do
  sleep 1
done
```

To wait for a process to exit. If I would replace it with:

```
tail --pid=$PID -f /dev/null
```

Would that be more efficient for the CPU? Or does `tail` just use the same polling under the hood?

Comment: Is it your own child process? If so you can do `wait "$pid"`, or even just a bare `wait`.

Comment: Are you doing a whole lot (hundreds+) of these at the same time?  Because otherwise, I don't understand why you're worrying about efficiency.  Your `while` loop will spend the vast majority of its time sleeping (which does not consume CPU), so its average CPU load is very near zero.  Improving "very near zero" by a factor of ten still leaves you at very near zero.

Comment: @JohnKugelman It's not a child because I start it with "set -m", should have mentioned that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger There is another reason I want to avoid sleep: I trap the SIGINT signal and sleep blocks the handler untill it is done sleeping. Just wanted to know if moving to tail would have any downsides in performance.

Comment: Please don’t cross-post. Choose either here or on Unix&Linux, not both.

Comment: @Maestro, you'll get better answers (and commentary) if you ask your real question instead of a proxy question.  Giving appropriate background often helps, too.  "Which has better performance?" is quite a different question from "are there disadvantages to switching?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$PID` runs for 10 secs ...

- the `while` loop conducts 10 tests and invokes the `sleep` binary 10 times
- the alternatives invoke a single `tail` binary or a single `wait` builtin

I'd expect the `tail` and `wait` operations to be more 'efficient'.

Short of reviewing the source code for `tail` we can run some simple tests ...

```
$ cat testme.1
#!/bin/bash
sleep $1 &
pid=$!
while [ -d /proc/$pid ]; do sleep 1; done

$ cat testme.2
#!/bin/bash
sleep $1 &
pid=$!
tail --pid $pid -f /dev/null

$ cat testme.3
#!/bin/bash
sleep $1 &
wait
```

Timings for a 10 sec test:

```
$ /usr/bin/time testme.1 10
0.07user 0.21system 0:10.36elapsed 2%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 98392 maxresident)k
  ^^       ^^                      ^^^^^                    ^^^^^
0inputs+0outputs (26228 major+0minor)pagefaults 0swaps
                  ^^^^^

$ /usr/bin/time testme.2 10
0.01user 0.03system 0:10.11elapsed 1%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 27060 maxresident)k
  ^^       ^^                      ^^^^^                    ^^^^^
0inputs+0outputs (7207 major+0minor)pagefaults 0swaps
                  ^^^^

$ /usr/bin/time testme.3 10
0.01user 0.01system 0:10.05elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 18484 maxresident)k
  ^^       ^^                      ^^^^^                    ^^^^^
0inputs+0outputs (4904 major+0minor)pagefaults 0swaps
                  ^^^^
```

**NOTES:**

- tests run under `cygwin/bash v.4.4.12` in a Win10 VM running on i7-1260P
- `testme.1` - 10x runs showed 5x each for 2%CPU and 3%CPU (call it 2.5% CPU)
- `testme.2` - 10x runs showed 9x 0%CPU and 1x 1%CPU (call it 0.1% CPU)
- `testme.3` - 10x runs showed 9x 0%CPU and 1x 1%CPU (call it 0.1% CPU)
- obviously `testme.3` (aka `wait`) is not a valid option if waiting for some other process's child process to complete

The overhead for the `while/sleep` loop increases noticeably with time while we see minimal-to-no increases in overhead for the `tail` and `wait` options; eg, 60 sec tests:

```
$ /usr/bin/time testme.1 60
0.34user 1.16system 1:01.02elapsed 2%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 488804 maxresident)k
  ^^     ^^^^                      ^^^^^                    ^^^^^^
0inputs+0outputs (131123 major+0minor)pagefaults 0swaps
                  ^^^^^^

$ /usr/bin/time testme.2 60
0.03user 0.07system 1:00.34elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 26356 maxresident)k
  ^^       ^^                      ^^^^^                    ^^^^^
0inputs+0outputs (7200 major+0minor)pagefaults 0swaps
                  ^^^^

$ /usr/bin/time testme.3 60
0.00user 0.03system 1:00.06elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 18328 maxresident)k
  ^^       ^^                      ^^^^^                    ^^^^^
0inputs+0outputs (4917 major+0minor)pagefaults 0swaps
                  ^^^^
```